# TinyMCE jQuery ajax from not showing after save

Tags: jquery, tinymce

okies so i have a complete ajax system every page loaded is handled though ajax its alot of messy code at the moment so i wont show you.

The problem i'm having is when when i go to my content that loads TinyMCE it works perfectly, once, then once the form is submitted it uses `remove()` on the TinyMCE element then once it's done it gets the content from the server this then has a textarea for TinyMCE and it loads the weird thing is the content is not showing but if i click the HTML button the content is within the TinyMCE textarea.

I will try to show to explain a bit better using as little code as posible

so this is the TinyMCE call every time the conent is reloaded from the server

```
$(".addonContent form textarea.tinyMCE").tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '/script/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,code,",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,charmap,emotions,media,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "/style/style_content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
```

And this works perfectly the first time

now my ajaxForm code run and just before it submits the data to the server it calls

```
$(".addonContent form textarea.tinyMCE").tinymce().remove()
```

but then when the content comes back and Tiny MCE loads it will not show the content in the editor but if i click the HTML button the content shows

**EDIT** 
*This appears to be a bug with TinyMCE and Google Chrome as the below code works with IE8+ and works with Firefox i'm trying CKeditor now.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shut down a tinymce editro instance before you load a second one with the same id.
Use the `mceRemoveControl` execCommand here.

Comment: do you still call this: $(".addonContent form textarea.tinyMCE").tinymce().remove()   ??

Comment: no i'm not just calling, `$(".addonContent form textarea.tinyMCE").tinymce().execCommand('mceRemoveControl');`

Comment: it's just cos of the spacing and the comments system there is a single space between textarea.tinyMCE not a newline

Comment: Please see my edit your fix worked and the problem appears to be left as it seems bug in TinyMCE with Google Chrome, as such i have moved to CKEditor and that works perfectly